# sveltekit static adapter nginx deploy configuration

Tags: nginx, svelte, sveltekit

i have a go api that's also serving static files and a separate svelte-kit static site that i am serving with nginx.

There is a problem with the configuration with try_files i assume.
with try_files line #1, site works perfectly fine but i can't view static files since nothing is being redirected to go api which is serving those...

try_files #2 fixes static files but then the problem is that few pages are broken after i hard refresh the page, i end up with nginx 403 or 404 error.

I can't have static files working and pages working normally after refresh.
I tried something like that #3 example but it's the same...
Basically i want to access those static files at `mysite.co/public/images.logo.png` for example. Do i need a separate nginx block, i can't figure it out.

#### nginx conf

```
upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
        server_name mysite.co www.mysite.co;

        location / {
                root /var/www/mysite.co;
                index index.html;
                #1 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                #2 try_files $uri $uri/ @go-api;
                #3 try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html @go-api;
        }

        location @go-api {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                proxy_set_header x-forwarded-proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                proxy_set_header x-forwarded-proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

#### svelte.config.js

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const config = {
  preprocess: preprocess(),

  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: 'build',
      assets: 'build',
      fallback: 'index.html',
      precompress: false,
    }),
    prerender: {
      default: true,
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

i am serving static files at /public with this code (using chi router)

```golang
subFS, err := fs.Sub(a.PublicFS(), "public")
if err != nil {
    panic("failed to serve static files: " + err.Error())
}
r.Handle("/public/*", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.FS(subFS))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your static files will be available at the `mysite.co/public` path, add this block to your config:

```
location /public/ {
    include proxy_params;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @go.api;
}
```

It will redirect the traffic for paths that contain the `public` substring in them to the go api, instead of searching for those files on the svelte static site

Comment: I misclicked this as dovntote and i can't edit :c aaahhh, maybe an admin can do that

Comment: No worries. I edited my answer just now to add a line, so you should be able to reverse your vote.

Comment: fixed it, thanks for the answer btw, that worked wonderfully.